# yq command to remove a specific field

Tags: yaml, yq

Given a yaml file, I want to select the fields which contain "graph" under "dependencies:" and append them to another yaml file called backups.yaml.

for example:
Given a yaml file called myfile.yaml

```
services_list:
  - name: service1
    location: europe
    dependencies:
      - graph
    other_dependencies:
      - mac
      - linux
  - name: service2
    location: asia
    dependencies:
      - db
      - k8s
  - name: service3
    location: asia
    dependencies:
      - db
      - graph
```

and backup.yaml:

```
services_list:
  - name: my-service
    location: europe
    dependencies:
     - graph
```

The result of backup.yaml should be:

```
services_list:
  - name: my-service
    location: europe
    dependencies:
     - graph
  - name: service1
    location: europe
    dependencies:
      - graph
    other_dependencies:
      - mac
      - linux
  - name: service3
    location: asia
    dependencies:
      - db
      - graph
```

Tried million ways and couldn't find the proper yq command. Would appreciate your help in here!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info and update which implementation of `yq` you are trying with

Answer (score 0):

[Which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq are you using? Basically, you want to add a filtered array of `.services_list` from `myfile.yaml` to the array of `.services_list` from `backup.yaml`. The two implementations, however, differ in how to access another file (`input` vs `load`), and in how to `select` (i.e. filter) by condition (`IN` vs `any_c`).

Here's an approach using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -y '.services_list += (
  input.services_list | map(select(IN(.dependencies[]; "graph")))
)' backup.yaml myfile.yaml
```

And here's one using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq '.services_list += (
  load("myfile.yaml").services_list
  | map(select(.dependencies | any_c(. == "graph"))))
' backup.yaml
```

Both output:

```yaml
services_list:
  - name: my-service
    location: europe
    dependencies:
      - graph
  - name: service1
    location: europe
    dependencies:
      - graph
    other_dependencies:
      - mac
      - linux
  - name: service3
    location: asia
    dependencies:
      - db
      - graph
```