# yq command to append to another yaml file

Tags: yaml, yq

Given a yaml file, I want to select all fields which contain a key named "graph" and append those fields into another yaml file called result.yaml.

for example:
Given a yaml file called myfile.yaml

```
services_list:
  - name: service1
    location: europe
    graph: true
  - name: service2
    location: asia
  - name: service3
    location: asia
    graph: true
```

and result.yaml:

```
services_list:
  - name: my-service
    location: europe
    graph: true
```

The result.yaml should be:

```
services_list:
  - name: my-service
    location: europe
    graph: true
  - name: service1
    location: europe
    graph: true
  - name: service3
    location: asia
    graph: true
```

Couldn't find a proper command for it, would appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
yq e '.services_list | map(select(.graph))' myFile.yaml > tmp.yaml
```

to write the `select()` result to a temporary file.

---

Then use `load()` to read that file while updating `result.yaml`:

```
yq '.services_list *= load("tmp.yaml")' result.yanl
```

---

This is probably possible in a single yq call tho

Comment: your first yq command changes thw whole content of tmp.yaml to an empty list `[]`. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

As with your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77860947/yq-command-to-remove-a-specific-field), please provide [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq you are using. The solution to this one is essentially the same, just use the `has` function. Yet still, the two implementations differ in how to access the second file (`input` vs `load`).

Here's the approach using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -y '.services_list += (
  input.services_list | map(select(has("graph")))
)' result.yaml myfile.yaml
```

And here's the one using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq '.services_list += (
  load("myfile.yaml").services_list | map(select(has("graph")))
)' result.yaml
```

Both output:

```yaml
services_list:
  - name: my-service
    location: europe
    graph: true
  - name: service1
    location: europe
    graph: true
  - name: service3
    location: asia
    graph: true
```

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), use the `-i` flag to modify the file, with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) use a temporary file along the lines of `yq … > tmp && mv tmp result.yaml`.

Comment: using kislyuk/yq I get `Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'Y' in -Y`. Using mikefarah/yq the output is empty list under "services"

Comment: @jrz `unknown shorthand flag: 'Y' in -Y` is an error from mikefarah/yq. If you're using mikefarah/yq, don't try to run the approach written for kislyuk/yq (also, according to the error message, you seem to have capitalized the `-y` flag). As for the (thus proper) mikefarah/yq solution: If you get an empty result (as with @0stone0's mikefarah/yq solution), you either oversimplified your sample input (because the approaches from both of us **do** work with the sample input), or you've (inadvertently) changed something (as you did by capitalizing the flag in the other case) that made it break.